# SQL Server convert YY/MM/DD to proper datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have varchar in format yy/mm/dd. I want convert it to datetime format.

How to do that?

Comment: Replace `/` -> `-`, substring and concat into yyyy-mm-dd, cast to datetime

Comment: So 12/12/1 - is that December 1912 or December 2012 ? Sounds like the Y2K bug is back...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just cast the value:

```
select cast('05/01/12' as date)
```

This will work with American setting for SQL Server.  If you are using international settings (or need to be international compatible), then use `convert()`.

```
select convert(date, '05/01/12', 11)
```

Answer (score 4):

Option A: Setting [`DATEFORMAT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms189491%28v=sql.110%29.ASPX) before convert operation:

```
DECLARE @v VARchar(10)
SET @v = '13/07/26'

SET DATEFORMAT YMD
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, @v)
```

Option B: Using appropriate [CONVERT Date Style](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) - 11 in this case:

```
DECLARE @v VARchar(10)
SET @v = '13/07/26'

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, @v, 11)
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay! .. option B worked very well